# Как сделать тему WP настраеваемой из админки

Tags: cms, php, wordpress, вёрстка, шаблоны

Всем привет, подскажите плз или направьте где прочитать (поисковик толком не помог), как сделать тему WP более гибкой (настраиваемой из меню админки). 
Тобишь чтоб в админке был пункт меню "Настройка темы" и там можно было добавлять/отключать рекламные баннеры, вкл/откл слайдер, добавление лого или видеоролика. Чтоб далее не флудить - заренее СПС ))

Answer (score 4):

Здесь все подробно описано: [WordPress. Создаем удобную панель настроек](http://dreamhelg.ru/2010/04/wordpress-create-better-options-panel/)

> Сегодня, мы подробно рассмотрим процесс создания страницы настроек для темы WordPress, на примере замечательного фреймворка WooFramework.
>
> Затем, мы немного усложним задачу, используя возможности jQuery, немного улучшим функциональность страницы.

Comment: Громадное спасибо)!